# Can not get value of a NSDictionary key, get an error: The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation

Tags: ios, swift

could any body help me out of this bug? I can get the NSDictionary `hiinIdPair`, but when I am trying to get the value of the `tmpId` key of `hiinIdPair`, it throw me this error:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
```

below follows the lldb information.

```
(lldb) po hiinIdPair["tmpId"]
iV_Starter(371,0x198ebb310) malloc: *** error for object 0x10a7ddbb0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
(lldb) po hiinIdPair
{
    mongoId = 5521ae815730c6051476f8b1;
    tmpId = "#h20150405a215200a506705";
}
```

the code I'm using these variables:

```
var hiinIdPair = idPkg["hiin"] as NSDictionary
  if hiinPkg_7.tmpId == hiinIdPair["tmpId"]   as String {
    hiinPkg_7.hiin.id = hiinIdPair["mongoId"] as String
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's a bug from other part of the code. The code is terminated by bug.

Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: Please write this as a comment in my answer, not as new answer. Thank you.

Comment: I have commented your answer that I'm using swift instead of objc. I think I'm trying to make it clear that this bug is caused by code elsewhere, not the string issue. But thank you for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Be careful because `"tmpId"` is not a `NSString` in objc. You should add the `@` character.

Wrong:

```
po hiinIdPair["tmpId"]
```

Correct:

```
po hiinIdPair[@"tmpId"]
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm using swift, does it still matter?